# Heading and paragraph moving on resize

Tags: html, css

I have a serious problem with positioning my `<h1>` and `<p>`. I am currently using `absolute` positioning but when I resize the browser the text moves and I don't want it to.

I tried other methods to style it, all of them unsuccessful.

Here is the fiddle :

```css
billboard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 645px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("../images/billboard.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.billboard h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: WCManoNegraBta;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 60px;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
}

.billboard p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Aleo, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 325px;
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css">    

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"> 


<div class="billboard">
      <h1>resto</h1>
      <p>Where your taste meets our perfectionism</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is stranger for me is that on the suggested fiddle it works perfectly. On my code however the text is not shrinking to the viewport.

Comment: You're almost certainly doing it wrong if you're using `position: absolute;` for this. What are you trying to achieve? Please describe that explicitly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute position for h1 and p which will place them at specific location on HTML page (top position which is specified). But you have specified width 100% for both elements and used text-align center. This will make the elements stretch to full width of page and make the text inside elements to center-align. Now when you resize browser window it will move the text.

Solution to your problem can be, instead of using width 100%, use display block and place the element at specific location by using "left" and "top" css properties.

Here is updated style:

```
.billboard h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: WCManoNegraBta;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 60px;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    /*width: 100%;*/ /* No need to specify width to 100% */
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left:300px; /* Added left position to set p tag at fixed location */
}

.billboard p {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Aleo, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    /*width: 100%;*/ /* No need to specify width to 100% */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Nowrap property used so that line does not break/wrap, alternatively we can specify width of element. */
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 325px;
    left: 245px; /* Added left position to set p tag at fixed location */
}
```